# MongoDB, SparkJava using Maven Connection Error

Tags: mongodb-java, spark-java

Error Log :

> > Listening on 0.0.0.0:4567
> >     2014-11-27 00:37:47,570 WARN  - log                        - FAILED SocketConnector@0.0.0.0:4567: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind
> >     2014-11-27 00:37:47,572 WARN  - log                        - FAILED org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server@5595a5a9: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind

Comment: So the port `4567` is already being used by some other java process. Kill all running java processes and restart.

Comment: There is any other way to stop the java process from the code or re-use the same java process @BatScream

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you didn't terminate spark properly and it's still running and bound to the default port 4567.

Just close the previous process and restart.  If you can't find it or it's running in the background you can use NETSTAT to find the process and kill it.

on windows `netstat -b` to find the process